# Are PayPal username, password and signature secure and private?

Tags: paypal

I'm developing web-service, where one users (companies) can receive payments directly from another (company's customers). Currently company need to enter its PayPal username, password and signature to receive payments via express checkout api. Is it normal, that users (companies in my case) will enter their PayPal credentials on remote site or it's secure information? I can't find any information about it. But i found, that some services work in the same way:

- http://www.getharvest.com/help/invoices-and-estimates/online-payment-and-gateways/paypal-website-payments-pro
- http://support.getresponse.com/faq/how-find-api-login-data-paypal
- help.wildapricot.com/display/DOC/PayPal+Payments+Pro
  Also i found another way for receiving direct payments - generate button (on the PayPal site or manually), where you need only PayPal email of seller. What the differences between these methods, its advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are considered private. Since it grants you access to all API operations, it can also be used to empty your PayPal account.

What I would recommend instead of collecting API credentials, is to use 'third-party permissions'.
This means initially requesting permission from the account holder via a pop-up dialog.  Once granted, you'll receive an access token. This access token can then be included in the HTTP header of your API calls to make calls on behalf of the customer.

Your users can either manually grant permissions to you (they'll need to log into their PayPal account and navigate to the right section within their Profile), or, if you want to make it easier, you can implement the 'Permissions API'.

I would suggest taking a look at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/permissions/ for more information.

To get started, sign up for an 'application' with PayPal via https://apps.paypal.com/.
Ensure you request access to the Permissions Service and receive an Application ID.

This will be the AppID for the Live environment. For Sandbox, you can use APP-80W284485P519543T.